# Get color code in attribute variation Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am replicating the colorpicker filter in woocommerce:
[image]

I have been searching but I am not finding the color value in HTML or in RGB. This is the attribute objetct:

WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 242 [name] => Amarillo [slug] => amarillo [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 242 [taxonomy] => pa_rasan-monocolor [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [filter] => raw [meta_value] => 0 )

Where can this field be?

[image]

with the

```
get_term_meta($attribute_value->term_id))
```

Tt is showing all colors:

```
array(3) { ["order_pa_rasan-monocolor"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["pa_monocolor_yith_wccl_value"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "#d4be16" }
```

How can I relate one attribute with its color?

Comment: check to see if it is in the terms meta - `var_dump(get_term_meta($yourObject->term_id));` - OR `var_dump(get_term_meta( get_queried_object_id()));`

Comment: or does the meta value change, if you don't select the first color?

Comment: Okey, with the get_term_meta($attribute_value->term_id)) it is showing all colors:  `array(3) { ["order_pa_rasan-monocolor"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["pa_monocolor_yith_wccl_value"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "#d4be16" }` . How can I relate one attribute with its color? Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Add that to the question - Now you just need to figure out, how to see which one is selected

Comment: `#d4be16` is your yellow color tho - That seems like it is the one selected

Comment: That yellow is eeee22. I only copy the first color but it is showing an array with all colors in the data base.

Comment: Show everything then - we might be able to see a connection. - right now you are only showing us one

Comment: Okey, for each value I receipt this ` array(3) { ["order_pa_rasan-monocolor"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "0" } ["pa_monocolor_yith_wccl_value"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "#d4be16" } ["pa_rasan-monocolor_yith_wccl_value"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(7) "#eeee22" } } ` . Is the second one (pa_rasan-monocolor_yith_wccl_value). I don't know what is the pa_monocolor_yith_wccl_value color value but, okey. I think is solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the comments helped me, but here is some code more detailed on how to get the color code of the variations :

```
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'pa_nameofthevariation',
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo get_term_meta($term->term_id)["color"][0]; // Ex: #d4be16
}
```

Comment: For me the key was `product_attribute_color` and not `color`, but apart from this it was what I was looking for! :)